# PHP catch (Exception $e) redirect to header("Location:

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

Production server Debian Apach2.4 behind nginx, requires Java which (very rarely) gets an OOM failure (corrected by cron 1 minute "if no service, restart".)

I'm looking to send a 503 page (curls perfectly).  Following code fails (blank screen):

```
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
    /* redirect to browser */
    header("Location: https://example.com/error/503.html"); 
    die;
    }
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `try` to match the `catch`?

Comment: If you're calling a Java program using something like `shell_exec()`, an error in that program won't cause a PHP exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a `try`:

```
try {
    $results = $solr->search($query, 0, 30, $params);
    return $results;
}
```

And no, no `shell_exec()`
I might add that during sandbox development we had:

```
die("<html><head><title>SEARCH EXCEPTION</title><body><pre>{$e->__toString()}</pre></body></html>");
```

But obviously do not want that in production. I suppose that I could rewrite the `die("<html>` line with a "full 503" webpage, but was looking for a more elegant solution.